# How to access Azure AD integrated Postgres DB using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, postgresql-11, azure-postgresql

We are having a PostgreSQL single service instance running in Azure, which is Azure AD integrated. So to connect via `psql` I follow this steps:

1. Log in via `az login`
2. Retrieve access token `$env:PGPASSWORD=$(az account get-access-token --resource-type oss-rdbms --query accessToken --output tsv)`
3. Login `psql "host=single-server-instance.postgres.database.azure.com user=aad_group@single-server-instance dbname=demodb"`

So far so good. But how would I do that with Spring Data JPA?

This is what my current `application.properties` file looks like. Of course I don't want to insert the access token over and over again.

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://single-server-instance.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/demodb
spring.datasource.username=aad_group@single-server-instance
spring.datasource.password=eyJ...there goes the access token

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect    
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

This are my dependencies from `build.gradle`.

```
// ...
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
// ...
```

**Questions:**

1. Should I move the `spring.datasource` and `spring.jpa` configuration part into my code and supply the access token to the `spring.datasource.password` from there? If so, how can I do this? Where should it go?
2. How can I retrieve an access token and pass it to Spring Data?
3. How should I deal with the caching of the access token? Do I have to take care of the refresh token and deal with access token expiry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've extended a *HikairDataSource* and overrided its *getPassword()* method, which is called before creation of new connection.

```
import com.azure.core.credential.AccessToken;
import com.azure.core.credential.SimpleTokenCache;
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenCredential;
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenRequestContext;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
public class AzureAdDataSource extends HikariDataSource {

    private final SimpleTokenCache cache;

    public AzureAdDataSource(TokenCredential aadTokenCredential) {
        this.cache = new SimpleTokenCache(() -> aadTokenCredential.getToken(createRequestContext()));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        final AccessToken accessToken = cache.getToken()
                                             .retry(1L)
                                             .blockOptional()
                                             .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Attempt to retrieve AAD token failed"));
        return accessToken.getToken();
    }

    private static TokenRequestContext createRequestContext() {
        return new TokenRequestContext().addScopes("https://ossrdbms-aad.database.windows.net/.default");
    }
}
```

used libs: `'com.azure:azure-identity:1.3.3', 'com.zaxxer:HikariCP:4.0.3'`

adjust properties, or create the instance of AzureAdDataSource in configuration file instead annotating it as Component:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://single-server-instance.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/demodb
spring.datasource.hikari.username=aad_group@single-server-instance
```

Answer (score 1):

Now Azure provides Spring starter libraries and PostgreSQL is among them
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/postgresql-support#connect-to-azure-postgresql-locally-without-password